# Memory leak in ionic app

Tags: angularjs, memory-leaks, ionic-framework

This is my first ionic app.
I think I have a memory leak issue, here is my code :

```
app.controller('ArtistsCtrl', ['$scope', '$cordovaGeolocation', '$ionicLoading', '$http', '$ionicPlatform', '$rootScope', 'UserService', '$timeout', function($scope, $cordovaGeolocation, $ionicLoading, $http, $ionicPlatform, $rootScope, UserService, $timeout) {

var posOptions = {timeout: 20000, enableHighAccuracy: true, maximumAge: 36000};

function gps(posOptions)
{
    $scope.searching = true;

    $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions).then(function(position) {

        $scope.searching = false;

      //  var lat  = position.coords.latitude,
      //     long = position.coords.longitude;

        var lat  = 40.821216,
            long = -73.942684;

           console.log(lat, long);

        json_url = ('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+ lat +','+ long + '&key=123456789');

        $http.get(json_url).then(function(response) {
            // console.log(response.data);

            $ionicLoading.hide();

            $scope.address = response.data;

            var address_components = $scope.address.results[0].address_components,
                levels_arr = [];


            // United States
            for(var i = 0; i < address_components.length; i++){
                if(address_components[i].types[0] == 'locality'){
                    levels_arr.push(address_components[i]);
                }else if(address_components[i].types[0] == 'sublocality'){
                    levels_arr.push(address_components[i]);
                }else if(address_components[i].types[0] == 'neighborhood'){
                    levels_arr.push(address_components[i]);
                }else if(address_components[i].types[0] == 'political'){
                    levels_arr.push(address_components[i]);

                    console.log(address_components[i]);

                    var nyc = ['Bronx', 'Manhattan', 'Staten Island', 'Queens', 'Brooklyn'];

                    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                      if(inArray(address_components[i].long_name, nyc)){
                        levels_arr.push({long_name: "New York City", short_name: "New York City", types: ["locality"]});
                      }
                    }
                }
            };

            console.log(levels_arr);

            var locations = valuesToArray(levels_arr);
            var levels = [];
            var positions = [];

            for(var i = 0; i < levels_arr.length; i++){
                levels[i] = locations[i]['types'][0];
                positions[i] = locations[i]['short_name'];

                // console.log(positions[i]);

                if(positions[i] == 'Upper Manhattan'){
                  positions[i] = 'Harlem';
                }else{
                  positions[i] = locations[i]['short_name'];
                }
            }

            $scope.tabs = [];
            $scope.artistslist = [];

            for(var i=0;i<positions.length;i++){
                $scope.tabs.push({"position" : i, "text" : positions[i]});
            }

            if($scope.tabs.length > 0){
                $scope.tablebox = true;
            }
            console.log('niveaux et valeurs',levels, positions);

            // we fill every levels with artists
            if(levels[0] && positions[0]){
              $scope.hasMoreData0 = true;
              $scope.artistslist0 = [];

              var page = 2;

              $scope.populateList0 = function() {
                $scope.spin = true;

                $http.get('api?level='+levels[0]+'&value='+positions[0]+'&p='+page).then(function(response){
                    page++;

                    console.log(response);

                    $scope.spin = false;
                    if(response.data.length > 0){
                      angular.forEach(response.data, function(response){
                          $scope.artistslist0.push(response);
                      });
                    }else{
                      $scope.hasMoreData0 = false;
                    }
                });
                $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
              };

              $http.get('api?level='+levels[0]+'&value='+positions[0]).then(function(response){
                  $scope.artistslist0 = response.data;

                  console.log('0',response.data);
              });
            }

            if(levels[1] && positions[1]){
                $scope.artistslist1 = [];
                $scope.hasMoreData1 = true;

                var page = 2;

                $scope.populateList1 = function() {
                  $scope.spin = true;

                  $http.get('api?level='+levels[1]+'&value='+positions[1]+'&p='+page).then(function(response){
                      page++;

                      console.log(response);

                      $scope.spin = false;

                      if(response.data.length > 0){
                        angular.forEach(response.data, function(response){
                            $scope.artistslist1.push(response);
                        });
                      }else{
                        $scope.hasMoreData1 = false;
                      }
                  });
                  $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
                };

                $http.get('api?level='+levels[1]+'&value='+positions[1]).then(function(response){
                    $scope.artistslist1 = response.data;

                    console.log('1', response.data, 'api?level='+levels[1]+'&value='+positions[1]);
                });
            }

            if(levels[2] && positions[2]){
                $scope.hasMoreData2 = true;
                $scope.artistslist2 = [];

                var page = 2;

                $scope.populateList2 = function() {
                  $scope.spin = true;

                  $http.get('api?level='+levels[2]+'&value='+positions[2]+'&p='+page).then(function(response){
                      page++;

                      $scope.spin = false;


                      if(response.data.length > 0){
                        angular.forEach(response.data, function(response){
                            $scope.artistslist2.push(response);
                        });
                      }else{
                        $scope.hasMoreData2 = false;
                      }
                  });
                  $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');
                };

                $http.get('api?level='+levels[2]+'&value='+positions[2]).then(function(response){
                    $scope.artistslist2 = response.data;
                    console.log('2', response.data, 'api?level='+levels[2]+'&value='+positions[2]);
                });
            }
        });
    }, function(err) {
        $scope.allowRefresh = true;
        console.log(err);
    });
}

$scope.updateMyPosition = function(){
    var onSuccess = function(position) {
         console.log('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
               'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
               'Altitude: '          + position.coords.altitude          + '\n' +
               'Accuracy: '          + position.coords.accuracy          + '\n' +
               'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy  + '\n' +
               'Heading: '           + position.coords.heading           + '\n' +
               'Speed: '             + position.coords.speed             + '\n' +
               'Timestamp: '         + position.timestamp                + '\n');
     };

     // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
     function onError(error) {
        console.log('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
     }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

    if(gps(posOptions)){
        console.log('fire !!');
    }

    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
};

$scope.gps = gps(posOptions);

var watchOptions = {timeout : 3000, enableHighAccuracy: false};
var watch = $cordovaGeolocation.watchPosition(watchOptions);

watch.then(
   null,

   function(err) {
      console.log(err);
   },

   function(position) {
      var lat  = position.coords.latitude,
          long = position.coords.longitude;
      console.log(lat + '' + long);
      // alert(lat + '' + long);
   }
);

watch.clearWatch();
```

}]);

A friend dev, talked to me about memory leaks, I have done some research but nothing concrete..
I can't find where it is.. Any help is welcome, thanks guys !